# Script to remove slash

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I need to search for the combination of back slash without code character and if found, I need to remove the back slash. I know replace functions like below, however I don't know how to remove characters.

```
awk -v RS='"[^"]*"' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\n/, " ", RT); print $0  RT}' file.csv
```

This I need to do on a csv file.

**Input:**

```
id,name,address
1,A,First Address
2,B, Second \,Address
3,c, ThiRd \" Address
```

**Output:**

```
id,name,address
1,A,First Address
2,B, Second ,Address
3,c, ThiRd \" Address
```

**Sample Input**

```
id,name,address
1,A,F/,irst /Address
2,B, /Second /,Address
3,c, //ThiRd /" Address
```

**As per Script got below output**

```
id,name,address
1,A,First ddress
2,B, econd Address
3,c, ThiR/d \" Address
```

**Output**

```
id,name,address
1,A,F,irst Address
2,B, Second ,Address
3,c, ThiRd /" Address
```

Kind of this

```
\(?!") -> remove back slash
```

Comment: Could you please post samples of input and samples of output in your post too and let us know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Updated the with samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Seems you have changed slash to `\` so adding this now.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /\\[^"]/){sub(/\\/,"",$i)}}} 1' Input_file
```

Following will be the code's output when I run it.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /\\[^"]/){sub(/\\/,"",$i)}}} 1'  Input_file
id,name,address
1,A,First Address
2,B, Second ,Address
3,c, ThiRd \" Address
```

In case you want to remove all occurrences of `/` then use following.(seems your output still shows 1 slash so only mentioning this)

```
sed 's#/##g' Input_file
```

Comment: I updated the question with correct slash, Could you please have a look. Moreover I want to remove when combination found not only back slash.

Comment: @user805, also why the 4th line slash is NOT replaced is it a typo?

Comment: Want to remove back slash only when it's not followed by "(quote) @RavinderSingh13

Comment: I mean not all back slashes, those back slashes which atre not followed by " then only we need to remove the back slash.

Comment: @user805, please check my EDIT solution now.

Comment: Seems like script is removing one more extra character, Tried on below sample. id,name,address
1,A,F/,irst /Address
2,B, /Second /,Address
3,c, //ThiRd /" Address Output id,name,address
1,A,First ddress
2,B, econd Address
3,c, ThiR/d \" Address

Comment: @user805, sorry I didn't get could you please wrap your examples in code tags in comments?

Comment: Updated the original question with samples, Please check @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @user805, try my EDIT and let me know then?

Comment: This time original back slash didn't get removed, input and output are same @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @user805, it worked ok for me I will grab lunch and test it then.

Comment: Not sure why it didn't worked for me. Sure @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @user805, I pasted the output in my post it looks to be working fine for me, could you please check if you have control M characters in your Input_file by doing `cat -v Input_file` if yes then remove them by doing `tr -d '\r  < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` and let me know then?

Comment: That's true. It's working. Thanks a lot @RavinderSingh13

Answer (score 0):

Using perl, this can be solved easily by Negative lookahead. I used your "**Sample Input**" as my input and got the required output as in your "**Output**"

```
> cat input_file.dat
id,name,address
1,A,F/,irst /Address
2,B, /Second /,Address
3,c, //ThiRd /" Address
> perl -pe ' $_=~s#/(?!")##g ' input_file.dat
id,name,address
1,A,F,irst Address
2,B, Second ,Address
3,c, ThiRd /" Address
>
```